# Flutter textfield Flutter RTL cursor position problem n-1

Tags: flutter, textfield, register-transfer-level

I don't know if the problem is old but I tried all ways to find a solution without success.
the problem when select letter n in input field the cursor jump to n-1 the problem shown in video included , problem in rtl only

The link contains the code and a video of the problem.

the code :
 [link  here](https://github.com/ebrahimhalaby/flutter-RTL/blob/main/main.dart)

the video :
[link here](https://github.com/ebrahimhalaby/flutter-RTL/blob/main/rtl_error.mp4)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the problem when select letter n in input field the cursor jump to n-1 , the problem shown in video included , problem in rtl only

Comment: @EbrahimHalabi I have exactly the same problem and haven't found any solution yet. Please edit your question and exactly describe it as you did in your comment to be more clear. Maybe it can help us to find the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this because of some characters is encoded as 2 to 4 bytes.

Anyway this snippet can do the trick

```
TextField(
     onTap: (){
          if(controller.selection == TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: controller.text.length -1))){
             setState(() {
                 controller.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: controller.text.length));
             });
           }
     },
     controller: controller,
     ...
);
```

Comment: Thank you, I think it's a good solution but ,I think you moved the problem to the previous letter n-1 ,

Answer (score 1):

The answer that has been submitted as correct answer, does not work on cursor movement. It only works on tap.

You can fix this by registering a listener on text editing controller and watch over the cursor position:

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
_textEditingController.addListener((){
                if (_textEditingController != null) {
                  if (_textEditingController.selection ==
                      TextSelection.fromPosition(
                        TextPosition(
                          offset: _textEditingController.text.length -
                              1,
                        ),
                      )) {
                    _textEditingController.selection =
                        TextSelection.fromPosition(
                      TextPosition(
                        offset: _textEditingController.text.length,
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                }
              }
            );
}
```