# Flutter - move curser to the end of text field

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I have a problem moving cursor to the end of the text inside text form field while using RTL languages like Farsi. When I move the cursor to the end (position n), suddenly it jumps to one character before the end (n-1).
I've searched every where and found similar issue here ([Flutter textfield Flutter RTL cursor position problem n-1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72579246/16124033)) but the solution didn't work.
I have attached a video of the problem.[image]

Comment: Can you possibly provide code or video clip of the problem you are facing, because if using `TextField` and using props `textAlign: TextAlign.center, textDirection: TextDirection.rtl`, I am able to move to the left most digit without any problem. Is the first letter from the left you are defining as nth position ? Can you give some clarity in the question

Comment: I the added video clip, i dont see any issure related content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this by registering a listener and watch over the cursor position.

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _textEditingController.addListener(() {
    if (_textEditingController != null) {
      if (_textEditingController.selection == TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: _textEditingController.text.length - 1))) {
        _textEditingController.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
          TextPosition(
            offset: _textEditingController.text.length,
          ),
        );
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in `onTap` function in `TextField`:

```dart
onTap: () {
  if (controller != null) {
    if (controller!.selection == TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: controller!.text.length - 1))) {
      controller!.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: controller!.text.length));
    }
  }
},
```